# responsive img resizing doesn't work on iPad

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, resize, image-resizing

I am having troubles with my portfolio website being viewable on iPads and iPhones (iPhones - I have a seperate style sheet that loads based on screen size - but still isn't ideal)

I have a class for every image like so:

`<img src="6.jpg" class="resize" />`

and this means it is resized to the height of the window, meaning the  largest possible image on any viewer's screen:

`.resize {height: 100%; width:auto;}`

This works fine but on iPads and iPhones the images seem to display at a ridiculously large version of itself like 1000% or something thereabouts. Why would this piece of code not display properly on a mobile device?

Thanks

Here's my code:

```
<div id="maincontainer" >

<p><i>A Working Title</i></p>



<div id="img_container">
<img src="6.jpg" class="resize" /></div>
<div id="img_text">Caption text</div>

</div>
```

and the css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#maincontainer {
height: 100%;
max-height:100%;
width:100%; max-width:100%;
}

#img_container {
height: 100%;
max-height:100%;
width:100%; max-width:100%;
}

.resize {
height: 100%; width:auto;
}
```

Comment: A little bit more code would be useful ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just target the images of the #img_container rather then giving the images a class. Something like....

```
    #img_container img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This seems to work

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<style> 
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.container{
    width: 100%;
}

#img_container{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


#img_container img {
height: auto;
max-height:100%;

}

   </style>



</head>

<body>


                 <div class="container">

                    <div id="img_container">
                    <img src="6.jpg"/>
                    </div>

                 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a elegant way of making it cross compatible among browser/screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably going to the height of the its parent container. Instead of `height: 100%;` try going with `width:100%;`. If this doesnt work, could you paste your code?

Comment: This is a sample page: [link](http://stevebishop.org/images/a_working_title/index.html) you can view the source there. There is a container for the images and the captions which is also set to 100% height: `#img_container {
height: 100%;
max-height:100%;
width:auto;}`. If I put `width:100%` then the images won't be in the right proportion. My style sheet as you can see really has very little to it...

Answer (score 0):

You just don't have to add `width:100%` to `.resize` class (like @JCBiggar said), also delete the `height:100%` property, by default is `height:auto;`:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="maincontainer" >
   <p><i>A Working Title</i></p>
   <div id="img_container">
      <img src="6.jpg" class="resize" /></div>
   <div id="img_text">Caption text</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#maincontainer {
   height: 100%;
   max-height:100%;
   width:100%;
}

#img_container {
}

.resize {
   width:100%;
}​
```

**Working Example** (Fiddle):
http://jsfiddle.net/DLJrV/1/

Comment: hmm, I added `width:100%` to the parent `img_container` div but that doesn't seem to solve it. Any ideas? I can't add 100% width to the `.resize` class as then it won't resize the image in the correct proportion.

Comment: @Estidog: yes, now I could see some code, check my edit, that should work! ;)